# I cannot install android application after signing

Tags: android

I have signed them using the export wizared but when i transfer them onto my phone they just wont install "application not installed" my log cat reads "no content provider found for: null" the really fustrating thing is i exported two or three last month just to test it and they still install no problem. Am i missing something??
 If anyone has any idea what im doing wrong please help

Comment: Try to uninstall the currently installed non-signed app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to uninstall your non-signed app first, because the signed can't be installed while an unsigned is on a device.